# When is a value type / reference type constraint useful in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I'm looking for simple examples that demonstrate when the value type / reference type constraints are useful.

```
... where T : struct  // when is this useful?
... where T : class   // and what about this?
```

I remember seeing some very nice examples in the past but I just can't find them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It allows you to use `as` operator on T if it is `T:class`.

It forbids you to compare T with `null` if T is `T:struct`.

Note that if you omit `T:class` then you can compare T to null even when T is a value type.

[Note: I needed to edit this post a few times before it got correct. At least I hope it is now correct.]

Answer (score 1):

The primary usefulness that I've found in it lies with Marshalling and pinning the object in memory.

For example, I do a lot of work with internal structures that can't be auto-converted, or are sent down the wire as a byte stream, so I wrote this helper:

```
public static T PinAndCast<T>(this Array o) where T : struct
{
    var handle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(o, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I thought that creating new instances depends on the "T: new()" constraints, not on the class/struct constraints? Also, I'm not really familiar with Marshalling and memory-pinning in C#, could you perhaps provide a code example?

Comment: That all depends on the specific details. In my cases, I've needed to convert an existing set of bytes into a struct. However, creating new instances, specifically, does depend on the new() constraint. I've edited my response to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

"T : class" will force the generic type specified to be a class, not a value.  For example, we can make up an ObjectList class that requires the generic type specified to be a class, not a value:

```
class ObjectList<T> where T : class {
  ...
}

class SomeObject { ... }

ObjectList<int> invalidList = new ObjectList<int>();  //compiler error

ObjectList<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ObjectList<SomeObject>(); //this works
```

This forces an invariant on your generic type T that otherwise might not be enforceable.  "T : struct" would work the same way.  Note that you can also use this construct to enforce not only that the type T is a class, but also that it matches an interface.  The code sample I took this from also has

```
class MyList<T> where T : class, IEntity { ... }
```

which forces T to be a class AND also be an IEntity.

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware of the semantics of generic constraints - what I'm asking for is examples where the struct/class constraints are *useful*.