# C# Is Not Assignable Type - Generics

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

So I'm just hacking around with a state machine type I was working on and mostly wanting to just try out the Activator.CreateInstance method to see what it was like, and I ran into a problem where I cant seem to use the `where` clause as I would think.  I apologize ahead of time if I am just an idiot and everyone laughs me out of here.  So I have 2 small classes.

```
public class TransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo> :
    ITransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo>
    where TTransition : ITransition
    where TStateTo : IState
{
    public TransitionContainer()
    {
        StateTo = typeof(TStateTo);
        Transition = Activator.CreateInstance<TTransition>();
    }

    public Type StateTo { get; private set; }

    public TTransition Transition { get; private set; }
}
```

as well as

```
  public class StateContainer<T> : IStateContainer<T> where T : IState
{
    private Dictionary<Type, TransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>> _transitions =
        new Dictionary<Type, TransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>>();

    public StateContainer()
    {
        State = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public T State { get; private set; }

    public int TransitionCount
    {
        get { return _transitions.Count; }
    }


    public void AddTransition<TTransition, TStateTo>() where TTransition : ITransition, new()
        where TStateTo : IState, new()
    {
        var transitionContainer= new TransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo>();

        _transitions.Add(typeof(TTransition), transitionContainer);
    }
```

So on the line `_transitions.Add(typeof(TTransition), transitionContainer);` I receive a `cannot convert TransitionContainer<TTransition,TStateTo> expression to type TransitionContainer<ITransition,IState>` error.

If I change the generic parameters to

```
var transitionContainer= new TransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>();
```

it works fine, but I wanted to use inherited types that are new() so I could be sure I could instantiate them.

Again I apologize if I'm doing something incredibly wrong, I was just kind of ran into a brick wall and my googling led me in no good direction.  I didnt include any of the other interfaces or classes as they didn't seem to be part of the problem, but if there needed I can attach them.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue happens because:

1. `ITransitionContainer` is not a [covariant interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719954/understanding-covariant-and-contravariant-interfaces-in-c-sharp) over its type arguments.
2. `AddTransition` method generic arguments are [not constrained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12743632/3745022) to be [reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733748/when-is-a-value-type-reference-type-constraint-useful-in-c).
3. `_transitions` is not a dictionary with `ITransitionContainer` values, so without changing it to `Dictionary<Type, ITransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>>` we still won't be able to add even properly resticted covariant transtions.

#### Simplified example

Consider the following simplified case:

```
public interface ITransition
{

}

public class SomeTransition : ITransition
{

}

public interface ITest<TTransition>
    where TTransition : ITransition
{
    TTransition Value { get; }
}


public class SomeTest<TTransition> : ITest<TTransition>
    where TTransition : ITransition
{
    public TTransition Value
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

It will fail in both

```
public static void Do<TTransition>()
    where TTransition : ITransition
{
    ITest<ITransition> item = new SomeTest<TTransition>();
}
```

and

```
ITest<ITransition> item = new SomeTest<SomeTransition>();
```

If you make `ITest` covariant

```
public interface ITest<out TTransition>
```

, then it will fail only in generic method. Because here `TTransition` can be a struct and co/(contra)variance [doesn't work with value types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454932/3745022):

```
public static void Do<TTransition>()
    where TTransition : ITransition
{
    ITest<ITransition> item = new SomeTest<TTransition>();
}
```

But if you make that method [constrained to only reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365134/how-to-make-a-method-generic-when-type-t-must-be-a-reference-type), then it will work in both cases:

```
public static void Do<TTransition>()
    where TTransition : class, ITransition
{
    ITest<ITransition> item = new SomeTest<TTransition>();
}
```

Apply the same principle(`out` and `class`) to your two generic arguments and it will do the job.

---

#### Full solution for your specific case:

```
public interface IState
{    }

public interface ITransition
{    }

// !!!!! - Here we add out specifier
public interface ITransitionContainer<out TTransition, out TStateTo>
    where TTransition : ITransition
    where TStateTo : IState
{
    Type StateTo
    {
        get;
    }

    TTransition Transition
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface IStateContainer<T> where T : IState
{
    T State
    {
        get;
    }
}


public class TransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo> : ITransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo>
    where TTransition : ITransition
    where TStateTo : IState
{
    public TransitionContainer()
    {
        StateTo = typeof(TStateTo);
        Transition = Activator.CreateInstance<TTransition>();
    }

    public Type StateTo { get; private set; }

    public TTransition Transition { get; private set; }
}


public class StateContainer<T> : IStateContainer<T> where T : IState
{
    private Dictionary<Type, ITransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>> _transitions =
        new Dictionary<Type, ITransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>>();

    public StateContainer()
    {
        State = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public T State { get; private set; }

    public int TransitionCount
    {
        get { return _transitions.Count; }
    }

    public void AddTransition<TTransition, TStateTo>()
        // !!!!!! - Here we add class constraints
        where TTransition : class, ITransition, new()
        where TStateTo : class, IState, new()
    {
        var transitionContainer = new TransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo>();

        _transitions.Add(typeof(TTransition), transitionContainer);
    }
}
```

Comment: So should he add `where` and `out` to the definition of `interface ITransitionContainer` and `class` to the `AddTransition` method? I tried but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.  Just as Andrew said though I tried and still received the same error.  I've been looking through the stack overflow links and docs you've linked so I'll see what I can do!

Comment: @TravisScott I've given a so called **full solution** that compiles and executes fine for me under .NET 4.6.1 in VS2015 - doesn't that one work for you? Perhaps you can create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can be sure that there is nothing missing that could influence the result?

Comment: Sorry @EugenePodskal that was my fault, I got it now.  I thought I did go through it, but I needed to switch the Dictionary from TransitionContainer to ITransitionContainer.  Noticed it when I made a new project and was writing as little I could.  Sorry should have followed more closely, the Minimal Complete Verifiable Example worked perfectly I suppose. :P  Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: as a note though, I am getting a `System.ArrayTypeMismatchException : Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.` when `_transitions.Add(typeof(TTransition), transitionContainer);` runs.  I'll see what I can do

Comment: @TravisScott About interface in place of concrete class - ehm, that's actually was a my fault - I forgot to mention that dictionary should use interfaces - otherwise variance won't work. And about your ArrayTypeMismatchException you should probably ask another question, just with [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

That fails because generics are not covariant. The problem can be seen here:

```
TransitionContainer<ITransition, IState> value = new TransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo>();
```

That gives you the same error. You also get this error with something as simple as:

```
List<IComparable> list = new List<DateTime>();
```

Visual Studio tells you (basically) that:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<System.DateTime>' to 'List<System.IComparable>'
```

What you need to do is convert the object. You could create a `Convert` method that returns a `TransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>` and then use `.Add(typeof(TTransition), transitionContainer.Convert())` (or whatever you name it).

But the most painless option is to create an implicit conversion for your `TransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo>` object by adding this static method:

```
public static implicit operator TransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>(TransitionContainer<TTransition, TStateTo> value)
{
    return new TransitionContainer<ITransition, IState>() { StateTo = value.StateTo, Transition = value.Transition };
}
```

And that's it. :)

Of course, you will have to copy everything needed for it to work, in this case it seems these two objects are enough.

Comment: Oh okay, that interesting.  I'll be sure to check this out too!